# Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be the union of the coordinate axies, I want to show that $\mathbb{R}^3-X$ is homotopy equivalent to a graph

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be the union of the coordinate axies, I want to show that $\mathbb{R}^3-X$ is homotopy equivalent to a graph, and the question asks further "which graph"

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^4$ be the union of the $xy$-plane and the $zw$-plane, I wish to show that $\mathbb{R}^4$ is homotopy equivalent to a surface, the question says "which surface" and I have no idea.

These are some extra questions that were left, I'll be honest I have little idea. For the first one perhaps the graph $z=\frac{1}{xy}$?

---

**What do I know?**

I am happy (confident) and have shown that $\mathbb{R}^2-\mathbb{R}$ (the x axis) is homotopy equiv to $\mathbb{S}^0$ - and retracting it to these two points.

Comment: A couple of comments:  (1) just one question per post.

Comment: (2) a graph (a.k.a. "network") is a collection of points connected by segments:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering your first question.  Executive summary:  there's a (particularly nice type of) homotopy equivalence between three-space with axes removed and the cube graph.

---

**Claim 1:** Let $V = \{(x,0,0)\} \cup \{(0,y,0)\} \cup \{(0,0,z)\}$ (three coordinate axes) and let $W = \{(\pm 1,0,0)\} \cup \{(0,\pm 1,0)\} \cup \{(0,0,\pm 1)\} \subset V$ (six vertices of regular octahedron).  Then, $\Bbb{S}^2 \setminus W$ is a [(strong) deformation retract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_retract#Deformation_retract_and_strong_deformation_retract) of $\Bbb{R}^3 \setminus V$.

Define $F: (\Bbb{R}^3 \setminus V) \times [0,1] \to \Bbb{R}^3 \setminus V$ by 
$$
F(\mathbf{x}, t) = \biggl(\! (1-t) + \frac{t}{\|\mathbf{x}\|} \biggr) \mathbf{x},
$$
and check that for all $\mathbf{x} \in \Bbb{R}^3 \setminus V$, for all $t \in [0,1]$, and for all $\mathbf{y} \in \Bbb{S}^2 \setminus W$,
$$
F(\mathbf{x}, 0) = \mathbf{x}, \quad F(\mathbf{x}, 1) \in \Bbb{S}^2 \setminus W, \quad F(\mathbf{y}, t) = \mathbf{y}.
$$

**Claim 2:**  The space $\Bbb{S}^2 \setminus W$ strongly deformation retracts onto the [cube graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube#Cubical_graph) with eight vertices at
$$
\biggl( \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \biggr).
$$

---

In order to wrap your head around this, I highly recommend that you draw a sketch of the coordinate axes in $3$-space and the [dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) cube graph that has an axis puncturing the center of each square face.